# Shrink list of taxesand shipping cost in the order price list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

have created a cart summary page. In that, product price, tax ,shipping cost an d total order cost should be shown. In that , tax included country tax, state tax and special tax. That should be shrinker by default and when i click tax field  ,  all the taxes should be shown on the page. Kindly help me on finding it suggest me if thee is any plugins to do it

Comment: <pre>Material Cost :$304
Shipping Cost : $20
+ Tax Cost    : $50
 Country   : $20
 State   : $20
 Special   : $10
---------------------
Order Cost    : $374
---------------------
</pre>
If I click the "+" key, the country, state & Special should be shown. By Default, it should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe jQuery's `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`? There's not enough info about what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: <pre>Material Cost :$304
Shipping Cost : $20
+ Tax Cost    : $50
 Country   : $20
 State   : $20
 Special   : $10
---------------------
Order Cost    : $374
---------------------
</pre>
If I click the "+" key, the country, state & Special should be shown. By Default, it should be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... Used Toggle() to shrink and extract.. it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Added a button and used Toggle(); to shrink and extract the list and it works fine.